# Elasticsearch - filter geo_distance query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping type with two fields : location (geo_point) and type (short).

I want to list my places by geo proximity and use this kind of query

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "20km",
                "location": {
                    "lat": 48.856614,
                    "lon": 2.3522219
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "types": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "type"
        }
    }
},
"post_filter": [],
"page": 1,
"size": 50,
"sort": [
    {
        "_geo_distance": {
            "location": {
                "lat": 48.856614,
                "lon": 2.3522219
            },
            "order": "asc",
            "unit": "km",
            "distance_type": "plane"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Is there any way to only include the first 2 places of a special type (e.g. type=2) ?

Comment: you mean another filter on `type(=2)`?

Comment: No, imagine that the geo_distance filter would return 10 places of type 2 I would like to limit the number of this kind of places to only 3 for example.

Comment: you can use `top_hits` aggregation to limit size of a bucket, but this is across buckets and i don't think there's support for dynamic size calculation

Answer (score 0):

Add another clause to the filter like

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
    "filter": [{
        "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "20km",
            "location": {
                "lat": 48.856614,
                "lon": 2.3522219
            }
        }
    },
    { 
     "term": {"type":"2"}
    }]
}
},
"aggs": {
"types": {
    "terms": {
        "field": "type"
    }
 }
},
"post_filter": [],
"page": 1,
"size": 2,
"sort": [
{
    "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 48.856614,
            "lon": 2.3522219
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "km",
        "distance_type": "plane"
    }
}
]
}
```

Comment: No, imagine that the geo_distance filter would return 10 places of type 2 among the 50 results (size: 50), I would like to limit the number of this kind of places to only 3 for example (among the 50 results).

Comment: So not specific type but top 3 or whatever for all types?

Comment: Top 3 but only for type 2 (for example)

Comment: Try changing the aggregation to a top hits aggregation and inside it you can use the size parameter to limit it the number you need and can sort by distance as well